# Using R in QGIS (montecarlo spatial randomness)

Tags: r, qgis-3, montecarlo

[image]I have installed R (4.0.3). And I have activated R in QGIS, installing the plugin R processing provider. I am trying to use monte-carlo spatial randomness in QGIS.

According to my probably ill interpretation of the R execution console output in QGIS, the error is due to the fact that the package spatstat could not be loaded. I believe spatstat 2.0.0. is loaded but 2.1.0 is required.

The error says "Error: package or namespace load failed for 'spatstat.data' in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]):
namespace 'spatstat.utils' 2.0-0 is being loaded, but 2.1.0 is required
Error: package 'spatstat.data' could not be loaded

I installed the plugin 2 years ago, with all its libraries, to which QGIS is linked in my settings. I am wondering whether I should change the settings, for instance by using the system libraries rather than the user libraries, as it is now, because evidently the user libraries is not updated according to the error message. Or it may be a solution to update the plugin, which I think may update the libraries as well.

[image]

Comment: @BERA I attached the error message. If you right click in tne image it will open and will be easy to see the error message

Comment: I believe that the issue is that the spatstat dependencies are now incorrect. Awhile back, the spatstat package was split into 5 separate packages and quite recently spatstat.core split into to two packages and then was removed from CRAN. So, without a minor rewrite of the QGIS extension it will not work.

Comment: @JeffreyEvans I have checked out the folder rlibs, where are all the R libraries for QGIS, and there is a folder called spatstat, which I believe according to the error message that is not the right version.. However, I haven't installed this package into R. I have also seen in R studio that it is possible to download spatstat from Cran (repository). Should I install spatstat in R? and see what happens..

Comment: @BERA In short, I have opened the folders in rlibs spatstat.utils and it is the version 2.0.0 but it is required the version 2.1.0, how can I change this? And the spatstad.data package that I have was built under R version 4.0.5, but I have installed on my machine the version 4.0.3. How can I fixed thhese couple of issues?

Comment: Important question: anyone knows if the folder rlibs (C:\Users\david\AppData\Roaming\QGIS\QGIS3\profiles\default\processing\rlibs) was created when I installed the plugin Processing R provider in QGIS or when I installed R and R Studio?

Comment: @david007, make sure you are able to run your script in R/RStudio. Update the packages, if neccessary. Then change the `User library folder` in Processing - Options (R) to your local R library like in this answer: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/448349/199931