# Updating R folder in QGIS

Tags: qgis, r, update

I cannot run various R scripts in QGIS because several packages are not updated. For the same reason I actually need to update my R version.

Do you know if when updating R software the folder rlibs in which are all the packages used by R in QGIS will be updated too?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to update your R and packages you use, and then change the default settings in QGIS, to point out to your R library (instead of QGIS internal) like:

[image]

You can have R processing scripts in several folders as well.

Comment: Many thanks @Grzegorz. I have a question in order to change the default settings in QGIS. I have 2 R folder: 1)C:/Users/david/Documents/R/win-library/4.0 2)C:/Program Files/R/R-4.0.3/library. Which one should I use as a default setting in qgis

Comment: You can check which one is used by running `R -e ".libPaths()"` or just `.libPaths()` in R console if you are using RStudio or something similar. I suppose it will be the first one (`C:/Users/david/...`), as it is user specific. And you should be able to install/update packages to this one. You can also update all packages which are in default QGIS path using something like `update.packages(lib.loc = "/home/sapi/.local/share/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/processing/rlibs")` where `lib.loc` will be pointing to your QGIS profile/path.

Comment: Many Thanks again @Grzegorz Sapijaszko. Where should be run the code to update the packages which are in default QGIS  [update.packages(lib.loc = "/home/sapi/.local/share/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/processing/rlibs")], in the console of OsGeo or in the console of RStudio?

Comment: Any R console...

Comment: Many thanks @Grzegorz. I will run the code in RStudio. I think that the easiest thing to do is to update the packages which are in default QGIS path. Many thanks for your help

Comment: In the line of code that you provide me "sapi" is your username, isn't? I should change sapi for david, isn't? Like that: update.packages(lib.loc="/home/david/.local/share/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/processing/rlibs")

Comment: From the comment above seems you are using Windows and your library path is `C:/Users/david/Documents/R/win-library/4.0`. Use it in `lib.loc`, so `update.packages(lib.loc = "C:/Users/david/Documents/R/win-library/4.0")`

Comment: now it makes sense. The path to the folder rlibs where are all the packages is: C:\Users\david\AppData\Roaming\QGIS\QGIS3\profiles\default\processing\rlibs

Comment: Therefore it should be : update.packages(lib.loc="C:\Users\david\AppData\Roaming\QGIS\QGIS3\profiles\default\processing\rlibs"). isn't it true? Many thanks again. Best regards

Comment: Yes, just try :)